# Modificando privilégios com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7

Estou enfrentando o seguinte problema, estou aumentando os privilégios com "Elevated", mas depois de executar os.mkdir (), gostaria que ele perdesse seus privilégios e voltasse a ser um usuário comum.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess
from elevate import elevate
from os import popen

def is_root():
  return os.getuid() == 0

print("before ", is_root())
user = os.getlogin()

elevate(graphical=False)
username = input("Enter the name of the user to be created in /home: ")
os.mkdir('/home/' + username)
print(os.listdir('/home'))
print("after ", is_root())
```

Fiz um verificador se o usuário é privilegiado e, mesmo depois de executá-lo, parece verdadeiro onde significa que ele está com super poder.

```
[garden@server ~]$ python3 mkdir.py
before  False
[sudo] senha para garden:
before  True
Enter your name : user10
['garden', 'user10']
after  True
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de elevar privilégios e depois retirar, para que, em caso de exceção, o código não esteja sendo executado com um usuário elevado.

obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de fazer a operação que você precisa de privilégios, insira esse código:

```
sudo_uid = int(os.getenv("SUDO_UID"))
sudo_gid = int(os.getenv("SUDO_GID"))

# drop root privileges
os.setresgid(sudo_gid, sudo_gid, -1)
os.setresuid(sudo_uid, sudo_uid, -1)
```

Para elevar os privilégios novamente:

```
os.setresgid(0, 0, -1)
os.setresuid(0, 0, -1)
```

Comment: Não esqueça de fazer import do módulo pwd